# Website is not taking connection string from web.config. it is searching for app.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, f#

I have project with 3 tier structure DataAccessLayer, BusinessLogicLayer and Website.

In my DataAccessLayer I have used F# library project with connectionstring accessing from app.config file

F# code -

```
type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<"","MyConnection">

let connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.               ["MyConnection"].ConnectionString
```

App.config code -

```
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Data Source=MyServer;Initial   Catalog=MyDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=xyz;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Now I have given the reference of this dll in website BusinessLogic and Website project.

I am calling a function of BusinessLogicLayer to get data -

var MyDataList = BusinessLogic.GetAllData().ToList();

Now the issue is, the website is searching connectionstring in app.config file instead of web.config. I want it to take connectionstring from web.config

Comment: Your app.config is in your "DataAccessLayer" project is it?

Comment: Is F# project running in it's own process? If everything is running from IIS, it should have read from web.config. You positive you have `<connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyConnection"` section in your web.config?

Comment: yes that section is added in web.config

Comment: I suspect this won't work as the F# compiler needs access to the connection string at compile time rather than run time.  But I may be wrong.

Comment: Its working with adding app.config in web application directory. But not with web.config.

Comment: detailed information on https://stackoverflow.com/a/52252862/1767482

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the connection string by using below line of code -

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;

var connectionString=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Here is a reference : 
[Connection String from App.config](http://programmers.bhoomijunction.com/Article/connection-string-from-app-config-web-config-in-csharp-or-asp-net-31)

Answer (score 1):

you can have either a web.config for a web project or an app.config for an application.

as alternative you can load in custom configuration files see also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx

Comment: Thanks for quick response. actually automatically it is not making connection with web.config. I want to define connection string only in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but it still comes up before this one in a search:
[F# Type Provider for SQL in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107676/f-type-provider-for-sql-in-a-class)

In your F# Data Access, add in a function like this

```
let getDbContext connString = 
    match connString with
    | "" -> Sql.GetDataContext()
    | _ -> Sql.GetDataContext(connString)
```

Then in the C# code you can call getDbContext and pass in the connection string from **web.config** at runtime.

Note that the F# Data Access layer *will still need* to have the connection string provided there for the compiler to do it's job.