# F# type provider in DAL

Tags: c#, sql-server, f#, type-providers

I have a solution with 2 projects:

1. F# project (for data access + other functions)
2. C# web project (will consume functions from F#)

I will need to call SQL Server stored procedures, and am using FSharp.Data.TypeProviders to do the job.

```ml
type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection< "...", StoredProcedures=true >

let getDbContext connString = 
    match connString with
    | "" -> dbSchema.GetDataContext()
    | _ -> dbSchema.GetDataContext(connString)
```

*Insert:*

```ml
let insertItem dbContext item = 
    dbContext.CreateStoredProc(item.Stuff)
```

Or

```ml
let insertItem connString item = 
    use dbContext = getDbContext connString
    dbContext.CreateStoredProc(item.Stuff)
```

1. How would I consume this from C# so that I'm not recreating the `dbContext` every time I do an insert?

I don't want to expose the whole `dbContext`, just certain stored procedures through the F# DAL.

*Note: I need to pass in the connection string from web.config*

Similar question here doesn't fully provide my answer: [F# Type Provider for SQL in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107676/f-type-provider-for-sql-in-a-class)

2. I am able to set `getDbContext` to internal or private, but not `dbSchema`. Any way to not expose it?

Comment: "so that I'm not recreating the dbContext every time" Why don't you want to do that?

Comment: If I have it as the first insert, then I can create a dbContext, and pass it in like this: [items] |> Seq.map (insertItem dbContext)
I'm not sure if this is a good idea, but it made sense to not recreate the context each time...

Comment: Also, in the linked answer Tomas said "this creates a new db instance for every Factory" which made me think this wasn't ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not much mistaken, the context is an instance of [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx), which isn't thread-safe. None of the data context base classes I'm aware of, are thread-safe, and since you want to use them in a web application, you must, at the very least, create one instance per HTTP request; otherwise, the behaviour of your DAL will be defective.

On the other hand, *within* a single request, it may be worthwhile to reuse the same instance. Therefore, I'd go with this function design:

```
let insertItem dbContext item = 
    dbContext.CreateStoredProc(item.Stuff)
```

because that would let you create a single `dbContext` value associated with a single HTTP request, and reuse that for multiple database operations, because you can pass the same `dbContext` value to more than one function.

If you want to make all of this accessible from C#, it would be easiest on C# client developers if you wrap all the functionality in classes. Assuming the above `insertItem` function, as well as the `getDbContext` function from the OP, you could define classes like these:

```
type ContextShim internal(ctx) =
    member x.InsertItem(item : Item) =
        insertItem ctx item

type ContextFactory() =
    member x.CreateContext connectionString =
        let ctx = getDbContext connectionString
        ContextShim ctx
```

This will enable a C# client to use a Singleton instance of the `ContextFactory` class, and for each HTTP request, use its `CreateContext` method to create an instance of the `ContextShim` class, and then use the members on the `ContextShim` instance, such as `InsertItem`.

Comment: 1. Yes, I found out about the not thread-safe part when I tried to do  [items] |> **PSeq.map** (insertItem dbContext) and it failed.

2. Is there anyway to hide the dbSchema type used by the SqlDataConnection provider?